# Appending rows to existing Dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am extracting twitter data using the twitteR package and storing them in a dataframe x.

I first created the dataframe.

```
x <- data.frame(
  name = character(),
  screen_name = character(),
  id = integer(),
  description = character(),
  statuses_count = integer(),
  followersCount = integer(),
  favoritesCount = integer(),
  friendsCount = integer(),
  url = character(),
  created = integer(),
  verified = integer(),
  profile_image_url = character(),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

Then created a function to return the data of a specific user

```
adduserdata <- function(username = ""){
  user <- getUser(username)
  userdata = c(name = user$name,
  screen_name = user$screenName,
  id = user$id,
  description = user$description,
  statuses_count = user$statusesCount,
  followersCount = user$followersCount,
  favoritesCount = user$favoritesCount,
  friendsCount = user$friendsCount,
  url = user$url,
  created = user$created,
  verified = user$verified,
  profile_image_url = user$profileImageUrl)
  return(userdata)
}
```

I now want to get the data of each user in the list ns and append them to the dataframe x

```
ns <- c("realDonaldTrump","BarackObama")

for (n in ns) {
  user <- adduserdata(n)
  x <- bind(x, user)
}
```

But I get an error stating 'invalid factor level'. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Where is `bind` defined? Do you mean `rbind`? (1) You shouldn't iteratively add rows to a frame if you can avoid it, it scales horribly. If possible, add to a `list` the rows to be added, and then when you are done generating the new rows, then all at once do `newframe <- do.call(rbind, c(list(origframe), list_of_newframes))`. (2) It will complicate things later if your function relies on the presence of `user` in an enclosing frame, I urge you to not do this "scope breach". Instead, pass it as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a dataframe from `addUser` function.

```
adduserdata <- function(username = ""){

   user <- getUser(username)
   userdata = data.frame(name = user$name,
                         screen_name = user$screenName,
                         id = user$id,
                         description = user$description,
                         statuses_count = user$statusesCount,
                         followersCount = user$followersCount,
                         favoritesCount = user$favoritesCount,
                         friendsCount = user$friendsCount,
                         url = user$url,
                         created = user$created,
                         verified = user$verified,
                         profile_image_url = user$profileImageUrl)
   return(userdata)
}
```

and try :

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(ns, adduserdata))
```

Or

```
result <- purrr::map_df(ns, adduserdata)
```